# Допустимо ли дублирование кода ради повышения быстродействия?

Tags: c, дублирование

Все знают, что дублирование кода - это плохо.

Но считается ли дурной практикой дублирование кода, когда оно применяется для оптимизации производительности?

Например, случай удаления данных из массива указателей:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    if (_del_func != NULL)
        _del_func(array[i]);

    free(array[i]):
}
```

В данном примере на каждой итерации цикла происходит проверка, задана ли функция освобождения данных. Вместо многократной проверки мы могли бы продублировать код, например так:

```
if (_del_func != NULL)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        _del_func(array[i]);

        free(array[i]):
    }
} else {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        free(array[i]):
    }
}
```

Считается ли это допустимым, или выигранные крохи в плане производительности не перевешивают минусов, которые за собой неизбежно влечет дублирование кода - увеличение количества возможных ошибок, трудность понимания кода и пр.?

Comment: Вы замеряли время выполнения кода с и без дублированием?

Comment: Нет, но полагаю, что сто миллиардов проверок в любом случае потратят какое-то процессорное время практически зря.

Comment: Что мешает сделать отдельно 2 цикла?

Comment: Почему не `if() for() _del(); for() free();`? Почему вы считаете, что компилятор не сможет оптимизировать это лучше вас?

Comment: Подозреваю, что на современных процессорах выигрыша практически не будет. Он просто поймёт что это if всегда выдаёт одно значение и вынесет его из цикла https://habr.com/post/337000/

Comment: Ничего от не поймет и не вынесет. Это чисто синтетический пример, но даже он при компиляции при помощи **MinGW** даже в релизе имеет значительный прирост производительности в случае с выносом проверки за тело цикла.

Comment: У вас есть два инструмента "обьединения одинаковых частей" это 1)define 2)template. В даном случае возможно только define позволит сократить одинаковую часть кода. template тут не поможет.

Comment: @nick_n_a, разве в чистом Си есть темплейты? :)

Comment: Но ведь это не исключит дублирование кода, а просто его спрячет. Значит, все же, в ситуациях, похожих на ситуацию в примере, можно применять дублирование?

Comment: @Максим, вопрос в том, что станет проще с этим работать, если вы работаете с массивами и циклами, применяя в каждой итерации какую-то функцию, вам ничего не мешаете написать несколько перегрузок для функции, которая будет пробегать по массиву и вызывать данную ей функцию.

Comment: На самом деле, в данный момент я работаю с функциями обратного вызова в разрабатываемой библиотеке. Некоторые куски кода принимают целую пачку указателей на функции. Мне не нравится, что на каждой итерации обхода данных контейнера происходит проверка указателя обратного вызова. Хотелось бы его вынести за цикл, но тогда код распухает. Плюс проблема в том, что в некоторых случаях необходимо выносить несколько проверок. Например, тот же for_each для map, аналога std::map.

Comment: Да, нету. Привык что они есть.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Да, дублирование кода применять можно. В программирование есть много тонких моментов где можно оптимизировать код, особенно оптимизация циклов помогает ускорить код.

Теоретически ускорение будет. Посчитать на сколько сложно. У вас есть повторяющиеся части. Их можно объеденить макросами.

Минус макросов:

1. менее читабельно
2. невозможность отладки, но если уже всё отлажено - можно вводить.

Плюсы:

1. более короткий код
2. в случае правки не нужно 10 раз один кусок править (для данного случая).

```
// описать сокращение
#define MY_FOR for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
// юзаем
if (_del_func != NULL){ MY_FOR { _del_func(array[i]);free(array[i]); }   
  } else MY_FOR free(array[i]);
// убираем
#undefine MY_FOR
```

P.S. Программный код можно сократить/объединить

1. define (без потери скорости)
2. template (чаще всего без потери скорости, если в вашей среде они есть)
3. объединение одинаковых кусков в функции

Comment: Ну можно тогда вообще на ассемблере переписать алгоритм.

Comment: Макросами я пользоваться умею, спасибо. Возможно, их и применю.

Comment: @Anamnian нет, это усложнение, которое позволяет сократить к-во букв:)

Comment: @nick_n_a, почему вы так и не вынесли цикл с free из условного оператора?

Comment: я о том, чтобы сделать 2 прохода по массиву. Условный для del_func и безусловный для free. Хотя, вероятно, микрооптимизация тому виной.

Comment: @vp_arth нету тут два прохода. Второй цикл за `else`. Я часто встречался с такими конструкциями.

Comment: Я повторил нижнюю часть кода автора топика, используя сокращение define. Нету двух проходов - для оптимизации.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, вопрос тут скорее к изначальной логике кода:

У вас есть массив с данными и вы точно хотите сделать 1 операцию и, при условии, еще одну операцию, ну так и делайте две операции отдельно, зачем мешать разную логику в одном цикле?

```
if (_del_func != NULL)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        _del_func(array[i]);
    }
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    free(array[i]):
}
```

---

Другой вопрос, что **одинаковый** код с **разными** параметрами можно вынести в отдельный макрос:

```
#define FORLOOP_PROCESSOR(arr, size, processor) \
for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) { \
    processor(arr[i]); \
}

if (_del_func != NULL)
{
    FORLOOP_PROCESSOR(arr, size, _del_func);
}
FORLOOP_PROCESSOR(arr, size, free);
```

Такой подход не изменит кол-во кода, но увеличит читаемость, т.к. вы, фактически, заводите новую "функцию", для такой простой функции макрос вполне читаемый и похож на обычную функцию, разве что типов у параметров нет.

Другой похожий подход - завести именно функцию, тогда дублирования кода не будет:

```
// перегрузки нужны для массивов разных данных
void array_processor(void** arr, size_t size, void(*processor)(void*)) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            processor(arr[i]);
    }
}

if (_del_func != NULL)
{
    array_processor(arr, size, _del_func);
}
array_processor(arr, size, free);
```

Проблема данного подхода в том, что нужно писать разные перегрузки для разных типов данных, что опять же приведет к дублированию кода уже в этих функциях. С другой стороны, если вы один и тот же массив много где так прогоняете - такая функцию, теоретически, спасет.

Comment: Где то упомянуть что из _del_func обязательно вызывать free. Тогда... такой подход хороший.

Comment: Это был синтетический пример. Чтобы вы лучше поняли о чем речь, вот реальный пример: функция for_each() принимает хэш-отображение, а так же две функции обратного вызова - для ключа и для значения.  Функция начинает свое выполнение в том случае, если задано действие хотя бы для ключей или для значений. Я хотел бы избавиться от ста миллиардов проверок в самой сердцевине из множества циклов. Я могу продублировать код, но его количество увеличится в 3 раза: заданы оба действия, задано действие только для ключей, задано действие только для значений. А есть еще ситуации, когда код распухнет в 12 раз

Comment: Получается выбор из двух зол...

Comment: @Максим, я тогда не совсем понимаю, в чем проблема. Возможно, я без конкретного кода не понял вашу проблему, но такое ощущение, что вы опять пытаетесь сделать 2 разных дела в одном цикле for - разнесите разные функции в разные циклы, перед выполнением этого цикла проверяйте валидность указателя на функцию.

Comment: Не все можно разнести. Например, ваш пример, где первый раз цикл вызывается для _del_func, а второй - для free, будет работать гораздо медленнее, чем даже вариант с постоянной (почти бесполезной) проверкой на каждой итерации цикла. Кэш процессора тому является причиной. Плюс, вам нужно сделать 2 * size инкрементов, вместо size, потому что вы проходите дважды по одним и тем же данным.

Comment: @Максим, в таком случае ничего, кроме ручной записи вам не поможет. Максимум, как вы можете упростить себе жизнь - вынести каждый возможный вариант в отдельную функцию/макрос. Это ничего не оптимизирует (даже сделает хуже, вызов функции тоже ресурсы тратит), но вы улучшите читаемость. Опять же, на этапе разработки можно обойтись таким вариантом, как только вы закончите свое дело - можно будет выжать производительно за счет ручной подстановки необходимого кода.

Comment: Я пришел к такому же заключению.

Answer (score -1):

Дублирование кода иногда имеет очень большой смысл по быстродействию. Например если размер массива всегда делится на десять, а код простой и надо побыстрее, то лишняя работа в данном цикле это проверка границы массива.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) ++(array[i]);
```

Можно уменьшить в десять раз проверку границы массива.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ){
  ++(array[i]);++i;++(array[i]);++i;
  ++(array[i]);++i;++(array[i]);++i;
  ++(array[i]);++i;++(array[i]);++i;
  ++(array[i]);++i;++(array[i]);++i;
  ++(array[i]);++i;++(array[i]);++i; }
```

Или для любителей шаблонов:

```
# define WORKSTEP ++(array[i]);++i;
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ){
  WORKSTEP WORKSTEP
  WORKSTEP WORKSTEP
  WORKSTEP WORKSTEP
  WORKSTEP WORKSTEP
  WORKSTEP WORKSTEP }
# undef WORKSTEP
```

Comment: Встречаются ли такие гвоздеприбивательные оптимизации в современных проектах?

Comment: Компиляторы сами могут если попросить. Например: `for(int i=0;i<2;++i)a[i]=1;` любой уважающий себя компайлер превратит в `a[0]=1;a[1]=1;`

Comment: В вашем примере  можно сделать один раз i += 10; а в квадратных скобках руками написать i+1, i+2, ...)

Comment: Сложение указателей это лишняя работа

Comment: Подобные "оптимизации" уменьшают константу, но не асимптотику. Убивая поддерживаемость. Это допустимо, только если не является частью исходного кода, а выполняется неким препроцессором перед компиляцией. К тому же инкрементальные циклы очень хорошо предсказываются "предсказателем переходов", не ломая конвейер.