# Возможно ли передать область видимости в функцию в си?

Tags: c

В с++ существуют лямбда функции, в которых, с помощью [], мы можем передать область видимости, возможно ли что то подобное с указателем на функцию в си?

Comment: нет, разве что добавить в функцию аргумент(-ов)

Comment: нет. А чем простые аргументы не устраивают?

Comment: В си нету лямд, и не будет. Можно разве что через #define (что считается плохим тоном) передать куски кода в подключаемый файл. Получится ли локальный контекст передать - думаю да.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/895136/%d0%94%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-ifdef-define-%d0%b8-undef/895156 и  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868524/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f/868536

Comment: Примеры с define выше, если опишите ваш случай более подробно, можно привести пример как сделать свертку. По сути можно обьявить ф-цию `#define myfunct(a,b,c)  code` в define скрипте \  признак продолжения кода в следующей строке - т.е. в конце строки добавлять \. Локальные переменные define захватит. Это будет не совсем функция - это будет "свёртка".

Comment: @nick_n_a, я пишу дерево, мне нужно использовать его с 2 разными структурами, по этому, в качестве поля data в ноде дерева указатель на void. Соответственно, предикат для сравнения этих data я передаю с помощью указателя на функцию. Так вот, после заполнения этого дерева, на его основе, я хочу заполнить другое дерево. Я хочу сделать это с помощью обхода и передавать в функцию обхода в качестве аргумнета указатель на функцию, который принимает в себя параметр data. С помощью этого обхода я хочу и печатать и заполнять другое дереве, иными словами, мне нужно как то передать контекст в эту функцию

Comment: Посмотрите как это реализовано в bsearch и qsort. (надеюсь что это не плюсоыве ф-ции)

Comment: @DenverToha, сделай дополнительный непрозрачный параметр в callback'е...

Comment: @nick_n_a насчёт *...нет и не будет* я бы не зарекался. Шаблоны (в каком-то виде) же подвезли в C11...

Comment: @0andriy Интересно зачем используют си, кроме микроконтроллеров и каких-то системных вещей как ядро линукс, драйвера и т п. Ветка микроконтроллеров будет развиваться значительно медленее. Я думю что си стал облегченной версией с++, и именно эта простота и привлекает разработчиков отдельных отрослей.

Comment: @0andriy, в каком?

Comment: http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html